# Parse.com Table Value Computation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have two Tables. "Vote" and "Post". The "Vote" table has a column, "value". The "Post" table has a column, "score". I'd like to somehow have the "Score" of a Post instance to be the sum of all its respective Vote's scores. I don't want to call all the votes to the front end, and then evaluate the score value. Is there some way I could have the "score" value be automatically computed?

Thanks!

Comment: Use cloud code and set up an aftersave for class "Vote".  This will trigger each time a new vote is saved.  Use this to keep track.

Comment: @Yepher - He's using parse.com

Comment: Assuming that Vote also has a column that is a pointer to the post, you can update the Post score column by sending the Post object the incrementKey:byAmount: message, the amount would be the Vote value then saving the object.